# Making a second database query based on the first

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, coldfusion

So I am porting a legacy application over from coldfusion to asp.net/c#. My problem is, (and I have searched all over for it, but I may not be wording my problem properly to get good results), is that I want to take my results from a the first query I have, and perform a second query to fill in that column.

Here's how I did it in coldfusion:

```
<cfquery name="p" datasource="db">
   select * from table
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="p">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="page.cfm?id=#p.id#">#p.title#</a>
      </td>
      <td">
         #p.category#
      </td>
      <td>
         #CreateObject("component","/components.dao").getuser(p.userid).user_fullname()#
      </td>
   </tr>
</cfloop>
```

You'll notice I call a component and method that I send the userid from the query too. This method has another query that calls a seperate database, and returns information on that user, in this case the full name rather than just the userid. This is where I am having problems in asp.net/c# for that I have created the following code:

```
<asp:Repeater id="program_list" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="page.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>"><%# Eval("title") %></a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <%# Eval("category") %>
         </td>
         <td>
            <%# Eval("userid")%> (needs full name convert)
         </td>
      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in the codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
      connection.ConnectionString = "***";
      connection.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)connection.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";

      SqlDataReader reader = null;
      reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      program_list.DataSource = reader;
      program_list.DataBind();
      reader.Close();
      connection.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Response.Write(ex);
   }
}
```

As you can see, it only does the first part, outputting the original query, but I am not sure how to interact with that query in order to call the database the second time for the users details. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just use a join in your SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you need to call an sql query each line of repeater. you should use ItemDataBoundEvent , in this event you can have processing rows user_id and can make another query.

for example

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drw = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem
        String sql = String.Format("Select * FROM UserInfo WHERE user_id={0}", drw["user_id"]);


        Label lblUserName = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblUserName");
        lblUserName.Text = //WWhatever you get from query...
    }
```

Comment: that definitely seems like what i need, but `DataRowView drw = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem` gives an error: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView' any idea what that is?

Comment: System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord rd = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem; try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event. You can do a query in that event and populate other controls.